# Login to server through PuTTY and then switch user

Tags: linux, ssh, login, user-accounts, putty

I am using the following batch file to log in to my server as root:

```
start C:\Putty_all\PUTTY.exe -v -ssh root@192.168.32.125 -pw password
```

When I have logged in, I want to change user to `oracle`. How do I do that?

Comment: That's what `su(1)` is for. **And change that password you published here as soon as possible!**

Answer (score 2):

You can specifiy commands to be executed on the remote system with the `-m <filename>` parameter. In the specified file you can have as many commands as you want (one per line).

So you can for example do the following:

`set ssh_cmds=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\TEMP\ssh_cmds.txt
echo sudo su - oracle > %ssh_cmds%
echo whoami >> %ssh_cmds%
start %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Putty_all\PUTTY.exe -v -ssh root@192.168.32.125 -pw password -m %ssh_cmds%`

This assumes that the user you are logging in with has the ability to use `sudo` without a password and `su` to the oracle user.

Comment: Well he's logging in as root, so he won't need a password *or* sudo.

Answer (score 0):

After login, run

```
su oracle
```

where `su` stands for "Switch User" ([or something similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)));. See `man su` on the server for more information on the command.

From the root account you don't even need to give the password, since you have full rights on the system.

Comment: no I have to login through that same bat file